# Security on $https requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yii, ionic-framework

Good Morning,

I'm developing an app in ionic and there are some $http requests(angular) that send data to a server controller(yii 1) to save data on database. I finished my app, but it doesn't have security. I was wondering how to protect it, because right now anyone if look my $http request can know what parameters have to send, and kill my app.

What I should do to protect it? Maybe through tokens? I'm really lost with security methods.

Thank you so much,

Carles.

Comment: Searching for "ionic framework auth" gave https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well When you research web application security you will come across Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). This attack vector is taking advantage of cookies, but in a preventable way.

Most attacks focus on stealing your cookies because nearly every website uses cookies as a form of authentication. The setup is this: when a user logs into your server, you set a cookie in the browser. This cookie contains a unique ID which is a link to the user’s session information in your database. The browser supplies this cookie on future requests, and the server knows who you are.

On the surface this sounds not-so-bad, but here is the catch: the web browser can be tricked into making requests to your server, even if the end-user didn’t perform the action themselves.

**Using POST Requests**

It is sometimes thought that using proper form-based POST requests will mitigate this attack, but that is not true.

**Using HTTP-Only or Secure cookies**

While you definitely should use these flags on your session cookie, they don’t implicitly stop the attack: the browser still sends the cookies to your domain when a request is made to your domain. Your server does not know if this is a real user or an attack.

**How To Prevent CSRF**

You can achieve this by relying on a set of rules that browsers respect, called the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This policy asserts that certain sensitive operations are performed by JavaScript code that is running on our website, not some other website.

Angular packages the CSRF token approach, making it simpler for us to implement. For every request that your Angular application makes of your server, the Angular $http service will do these things automatically:

Look for a cookie named XSRF-TOKEN on the current domain.
If that cookie is found, it reads the value and adds it to the request as the X-XSRF-TOKEN header.

Thus the client-side implementation is handled for you, automatically! But this does leave the server side pieces in your hands. You will need to do the following parts:

During login: create the CSRF token (with a random, un-guessable string), and associate it with the user session. You will need to send it on the login response as the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.
Assert that all incoming requests to your API have the X-XSRF-TOKEN header, and that the value of the header is the token that is associated with the user’s session.

That’s it! With a little bit of backend work, you now have a strategy which protects you from CSRF attacks.

you will find a working example of how to prevent CSRF attack [here](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/04/preventing-csrf-attacks-with-express-and-angularjs/)
and for theory of understanding CSRF attacks please follow this [reference](https://stormpath.com/blog/angular-xsrf)